# Web scraping in R with Selenium to click new pages

Tags: html, r, selenium, web-scraping, rselenium

I am trying to enter the different pages of this dynamic web (https://es.gofundme.com/s?q=covid). In this search engine, my intention is to enter each project. There are 12 projects per page.
[image]

Once you have entered each of these projects and have obtained the desired information (that is, if I get it), I want you to continue to the next page. That is, once you have obtained the 12 projects on page 1, you must obtain the 12 projects on page 2 and so on.

[image]

How can it be done? You help me a lot. Thanks!

This is my code:

```
#Loading the rvest package
library(rvest)
library(magrittr) # for the '%>%' pipe symbols
library(RSelenium) # to get the loaded html of 
library(purrr) # for 'map_chr' to get reply 
library(tidyr) #extract_numeric(years)
library(stringr)

df_0<-data.frame(project=character(),
                 name=character(),
                 location=character(),
                 dates=character(),
                 objective=character(),
                 collected=character(),
                 donor=character(),
                 shares=character(),
                 follow=character(),
                 comments=character(),
                 category=character())

#Specifying the url for desired website to be scraped
url <- 'https://es.gofundme.com/f/ayuda-a-ta-josefina-snchez-por-covid-en-pulmn?qid=00dc4567cb859c97b9c3cefd893e1ed9&utm_campaign=p_cp_url&utm_medium=os&utm_source=customer'

# starting local RSelenium (this is the only way to start RSelenium that is working for me atm)
selCommand <- wdman::selenium(jvmargs = c("-Dwebdriver.chrome.verboseLogging=true"), retcommand = TRUE)
shell(selCommand, wait = FALSE, minimized = TRUE)
remDr <- remoteDriver(port = 4567L, browserName = "firefox")
remDr$open()

  
require(RSelenium)

# go to website
remDr$navigate(url)

# get page source and save it as an html object with rvest
html_obj <- remDr$getPageSource(header = TRUE)[[1]] %>% read_html()
  
# 1) Project name
project <- html_obj %>% html_nodes(".a-campaign-title") %>% html_text()
  
 # 2) name 
info <- html_obj %>% html_nodes(".m-person-info") %>% html_text()
  
# 3) location 
location <- html_obj %>% html_nodes(".m-person-info-content") %>% html_text()

  
# 4) dates 
dates <- html_obj %>% html_nodes(".a-created-date") %>% html_text()
  
# 5) Money -collected -objective
money <- html_obj %>% html_nodes(".m-progress-meter-heading") %>% html_text()
  
# 6) doner, shares and followers
popularity <- html_obj %>% html_nodes(".text-stat-value") %>% html_text()
  
# 7) Comments
comments <- html_obj %>% html_nodes(".o-expansion-list-wrapper") %>% html_text()
  
# 8) Category
category <- html_obj %>% html_nodes(".a-link") %>% html_text()
  
  
  
# create the df with all the info
review_data <- data.frame(project=project, 
                            name= gsub("\\Organizador.*","",info[7]),
                            location=str_remove(location[7], "Organizador"),
                            dates = dates, 
                            collected = unlist(strsplit(money, " "))[1], 
                            objective = unlist(strsplit(money, " "))[8], 
                            donor = popularity[1],
                            shares = popularity[2],
                            follow = popularity[3],
                            comments = extract_numeric(comments), 
                            category = category[17], 
                            stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page does a POST request that you can mimic/simplify. To keep dynamic you need to first grab an api key and application id from a source js file, then pass those in the subsequent POST request.

In the following I simply extract the urls from each request. I set the querystring for the POST to have the max of 20 results per page. After an initial request, in which I retrieve the number of pages, I then map a function across the page numbers, extracting urls from the POST response for each; altering the `page` param.

You end up with a list of urls for all the projects you can then visit to extract info from; or, potentially make xmlhttp requests to.

N.B. Code can be re-factored a little as tidy up.

```
library(httr)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyverse)

get_df <- function(x){
  df <- map_dfr(x, .f = as_tibble) %>% select(c('url')) %>% unique() %>% 
    mutate( url = paste0('https://es.gofundme.com/f/', url))
  return(df)
}

r <- httr::GET('https://es.gofundme.com/static/js/main~4f8b914b.bfe3a91b38d67631e0fa.js') %>% content(as='text')

matches <- stringr::str_match_all(r, 't\\.algoliaClient=r\\.default\\("(.*?)","(.*?)"')

application_id <- matches[[1]][,2]
api_key <-matches[[1]][,3]

headers = c(
  'User-Agent' = 'Mozilla/5.0',
  'content-type' = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  'Referer' = 'https://es.gofundme.com/'
)

params = list(
  'x-algolia-agent' = 'Algolia for JavaScript (4.7.0); Browser (lite); JS Helper (3.2.2); react (16.12.0); react-instantsearch (6.8.2)',
  'x-algolia-api-key' = api_key,
  'x-algolia-application-id' = application_id
)  
post_body <- '{"requests":[{"indexName":"prod_funds_feed_replica_1","params":"filters=status%3D1%20AND%20custom_complete%3D1&exactOnSingleWordQuery=word&query=covid&hitsPerPage=20&attributesToRetrieve=%5B%22fundname%22%2C%22username%22%2C%22bene_name%22%2C%22objectID%22%2C%22thumb_img_url%22%2C%22url%22%5D&clickAnalytics=true&userToken=00-e940a6572f1b47a7b2338b563aa09b9f-6841178f&page='
page_num <- 0
data <- paste0(post_body, page_num, '"}]}')
res <- httr::POST(url = 'https://e7phe9bb38-dsn.algolia.net/1/indexes/*/queries', httr::add_headers(.headers=headers), query = params, body = data) %>% content()
num_pages <- res$results[[1]]$nbPages
df <- get_df(res$results[[1]]$hits)
pages <- c(1:num_pages-1)

df2 <- map_dfr(pages, function(page_num){
  data <- paste0(post_body, page_num, '"}]}')
  res <- httr::POST('https://e7phe9bb38-dsn.algolia.net/1/indexes/*/queries', httr::add_headers(.headers=headers), query = params, body = data) %>% content()
  temp_df <-get_df(res$results[[1]]$hits)
}
)

df <- rbind(df, df2)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your input. But when I try to run that code that you have given me, it returns me when I define the variable **df2** the following error: `Error in is.url (url): cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'`
I do not identify what the error is precisely, can you help me?

Comment: It's fantastic. Thank you. This code is great. I must try to understand it myself to be able to apply it in other cases. A doubt. I get 1020 projects. But I think there are many more in the link that you indicate (https://es.gofundme.com/s?q=covid). I don't know why you don't get all of them. This also owes me to running the code: `No encoding supplied: defaulting to UTF-8`. I don't know if it's an error or a warning.

Comment: I do not know for you it is very tedious, to be able to explain or send me a web where I explain the step of grabbing an API key for application id from a source js file and then pass those in the subsequent POST request. Go through 51 pages and as 20 results appear per page, I get 1020 links. And I think the key to be able to extract more links may be in the js file, right? On that page that I want to extract its links, it appears on the web that there are around 530,000 campaigns. How can I get more links, than all of them? @QHarr

Comment: Hi, Will try to review over weekend

Comment: No rush, when you can. When you get it, if it's not too much of a hassle, I'd like to know how to get an API key and application id from a source js file, then pass them on in the subsequent POST request. I don't know if there was a tutorial that would explain it. So I would try to identify how to get more links. Thank you very much for your helpful collaboration.

Comment: I do not know if you have been able to achieve it. Thank you! @QHarr

Comment: Were you able to do it? @QHarr

Comment: Sorry, I forgot. I will make a note now to look tonight.

Comment: Forgive my insistence. I do not know for you it is very tedious, to be able to explain or send me a web where I explain the step of grabbing an API key for application id from a source js file and then pass those in the subsequent POST request. Go through 51 pages and as 20 results appear per page, I get 1020 links. And I think the key to be able to extract more links may be in the js file, right? On that page that I want to extract its links, it appears on the web that there are around 530,000 campaigns. How can I get more links, than all of them? @QHarr

Comment: I don't know if you could solve it? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

@David Perea, see this [page](https://github.com/yusuzech/r-web-scraping-cheat-sheet/blob/master/README.md#171-javascript-heavy-websites) for differentiation of scraping methods, including Selenium. The method proposed by QHarr is very good, but doesn't use Selenium and also requires good knowledge of HTTP.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30178943)